# ASP.NET Authorization - bookmark issue

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I have an Intranet app that uses AD authentication and forms, based on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326340. It (relatively) works fine, I start the app and it goes to login page, etc. The problem occurs if I bookmark a page, close the browser, open a new one and select the bookmark. It correctly goes to login page with a return url specified, I log in and it clears the id and password text boxes, clears the return url text and sits at login.aspx waiting for me to login again. When I do, it goes to default.aspx.
In web.config, I set the authentication and authorization as:

```
      <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="5" />
  </authentication>

  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
```

In the folder that has the login.aspx, I added a web.config and set it as:

```
    <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I am NOT using a login control, just two text boxes for ID and password and a login button and handle the authentication on button click.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: when a user logs in are you using FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("username",true);? Because this should automatically get the return url, log the user in, and redirect.

Comment: After user is authenticated, I use the following: Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(sUserID, false))

Comment: I tried it with the API you suggested and it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: I was the problem! I was checking a session varibale in master page and becuase it was not set yet at first login, it would send me back to the  login page again.

Answer (score 1):

I was the problem! I was checking a session varibale in master page and becuase it was not set yet at first login, it would send me back to the login page again.